# Getting http status 401 unauthorized for the web request?

Tags: javascript, angular, api, web-services

I am invoking the service with authorization header, but I am getting the http status code 401 unauthorized access, interesting thing  is that if i try this with chrome or postman I am getting exactly result , that means there is no issue on server side ,then what I am missing in client side so that it is failing on options method?

Here is my code for that :-

```
 this.http.get(url,{headers:this.headers}).subscribe(res=>{
    console.log(res);
    });
```

Comment: try to set `this.http.get(url,{headers:this.headers, withCredentials: true}).subscribe(res=>{
    console.log(res);
    });`

Comment: I already tried this ,but still getting same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I don't have enough reputation to comment so I have to reply.

If you install [Chors Extension for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en) and it posts successfully, then the problem is likely because you are trying to access a service that you are not authorised to from a localhost.

My recommended solution would be to allow all relevant headers on your server, such as (pseudo):

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: localhost:8888

Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE

Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
```

If you have access to the receiving server, the easiest fix would be to add

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

to your server ([taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143093/origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)).

[See Mozilla resources for further reading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)